# Смена дизайна курсора в Winforms при наведении

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

Как сделать так, чтобы при наведении курсора мыши на определенную область `PictureBox` в Windows Forms менялся дизайн курсора?

Comment: Обрабатывайте событие `MouseMove` и устанавливайте свойство `Cursor`. Покажите ваш код.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Я реализую рисование кривых Безье. Я хочу иметь возможность перемещать одну из опорных точек при наведении на неё курсора. Код в 300 строк, что именно вы хотите посмотреть?

Comment: Реализуйте обработку события MouseMove. Если что-то не получится - покажите код, подскажем, что не так.

Comment: Ок, понял. Спасибо большое за помощь)

Answer (score 3):

Нужно проверять, что курсор находится над какими-то координатами контрола, как писал Alexander Petrov: отлично подойдет MouseMove.
В качестве примера - 2 квадрата, красный и синий, и обычный черный фон, при наведении на любой из них меняется курсор.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        var pictureBox = new PictureBox() { Height = 100, Width = 100 };
        var bitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox.Width, pictureBox.Height);
        var redRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 20, 20);
        var blueRectangle = new Rectangle(30, 20, 20, 20);
        var rectangles = new List<Rectangle> { redRectangle, blueRectangle };
        // Рисуем изображение для PictureBox'а
        using(var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)) {
            graphics.Clear(Color.Black);
            graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, redRectangle);
            graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, blueRectangle);
        }
        pictureBox.Image = bitmap;
        pictureBox.MouseMove += (s, e) => {
            // Проверяем, что курсор ни в одной из заданных областей
            if(rectangles.All(x => !x.Contains(e.Location)))
                if(Cursor.Current != Cursors.No)
                    Cursor.Current = Cursors.No;
            // Красный квадрат
            if(redRectangle.Contains(e.Location))
                if(Cursor.Current != Cursors.Hand)
                    Cursor.Current = Cursors.Hand;
            // Синий квадрат
            if(blueRectangle.Contains(e.Location))
                if(Cursor.Current != Cursors.Cross)
                    Cursor.Current = Cursors.Cross;
        };
        Controls.Add(pictureBox);
    }
}
```